# How can I grab the highest value in alphanumeric list using Python?

Tags: python, string, sorting, alphanumeric

If I have a list of strings such as `["A", "B", "1", "0", "C", "2"]`, how can I have Python elegantly grab the "highest" value (`2`) of that list?

For example, if the list above were to be sorted from lowest to highest, it would be

```
[A, B, C, 0, 1, 2]
```

and I would need to grab `2`.

using `sorted()`, organises the list in the following way

```
[0, 1, 2, A, B, C]
```

Comment: Why do you consider 2 higher than C? 2 is the 50th ASCII character, and C is the 67th.

Comment: @Kevin Whay do you consider C higher than 2? 2 is the 242th EBCDIC character, and C is the 195th.

Answer (score 7):

You could provide a custom key to `sorted` that causes nondigit characters to appear before digits:

```
>>> x = ["A", "B", "1", "0", "C", "2"]
>>> sorted(x, key = lambda item: (item.isdigit(), item))
['A', 'B', 'C', '0', '1', '2']
>>> max(x, key = lambda item: (item.isdigit(), item))
'2'
```

A more general solution could be to explicitly specify the kind of ordering you want. This makes it easy to change the implementation if you change your mind on what is "highest".

```
>>> ordering = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
>>> x = ["A", "B", "1", "0", "C", "2"]
>>> print max(x, key=ordering.index)
2

>>> #Actually, I've decided that A should be highest!
>>> ordering = "BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789A"
>>> print max(x, key=ordering.index)
A
```

This may be a little slower than the first solution, since `index` runs in linear time, but you may find the tradeoff worthwhile if you feel it makes the code more understandable.

Comment: Might as well replace `sorted` by `max` then, if you want the highest value - there's no need to sort in that case, which improves time complexity.

Comment: That's a great idea for a custom ordering scheme! I'm stealing that for my own bag of tricks, thanks!

Comment: `ordering = {k: v for v, k in enumerate("BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789A")}` with `key=ordering.get` and it's no longer slower. Or for whom likes it that way: `ordering = dict(zip("BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789A", itertools.count()))`. Yet I agree that your version is easier to grasp.

Comment: @Kevin, This is perfect.  Simple and Flexible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ["A", "B", "1", "0", "C", "2"]
my_list.sort()
print(my_list[-1])
```

However, this will print "C". [Letters are "greater than" numbers in ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters)

Do you want to consider numbers 'higher than' letters?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["A", "B", "1", "0", "C", "2"]
max([x for x in a if x.isdigit()])
```

Comment: This works for the sample input given by the OP, but what if he gives it a list that has no digits at all?

Comment: @Kevin yeah would need details of how the list is constructed and expected data.

Answer (score 0):

This iterates over the list and sets the value of `max` to the the value of each if each is anumber and greater than the current value of max:

```
max = 0
for item in lst:
    if not item.isalpha():
        if int(item) > max:
            max = int(item)
        else:
            pass

print(max)
```

Comment: Calling the variable `each` is very confusing. For example, `each.isalpha()` suggests that it refers to all elements in the list, yet it refers to just a single one... Rather call it `item` or `element`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get the largest number among the elements of your list, you could try casting the numbers to integers and then finding the maximum.

```
def casted_max(l):
    casted = [int(m) for m in l if m.isdigit()]
    if casted:
        return max(casted)
    else:
        return -1
```